# Filter properties similar to JsonFilter during deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson2

I am using Jackson 2 and struggled with dynamic filtering of properties during deserialization.

My idea is to load an entity and just read the changes:

```
objectMapper.readerForUpdating(entity).readValue(json)
```

I was trying to use `@JsonView`, which works for the simple cases.

I get an update of EntityA and the reader should only accept the id of EntityB, which is used to look up the foreign entity via EntityManager.

Using `@JsonView` allows me to handle it, but I need to have different view classes for all my use cases, f.e. updating EntityB only.

```
class Views {
    public static class Update {
    }
    public static class Display extends Update {
    }
}

class EntityA {
    @JsonView(Views.Update)
    EntityB b;

    ...
}

class EntityB {
    @JsonView(Views.Update)
    Integer id;
    @JsonView(Views.???)
    String value;
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to filter the properties dynamically during deserialization like the `@JsonFilter`?
I found an old answer to do it with [BeanDeserializerModifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473219/390177), but I hoped there is a better way.