# How to merge JsonIgnoreProperties with superclass?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(values="foo", allowGetters = true)
public class Parent {
  String foo;
  String bar;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(values="alice", allowGetters = true)
public class Child extends Parent {
  String alice;
  String bob;
}
```

This results in a class `Child` where the attribute `foo` is not ignored (for setting). So I assume `JsonIgnoreProperties` of `Child` overrides `JsonIgnoreProperties` of `Parent`.

But I need a way to merge `JsonIgnoreProperties` of `Child` and `JsonIgnoreProperties` of `Parent`. How to do this? TIA!

Comment: You can set ignoreUnknown = true which will ignore any or specify multiple using  value = { "alice", "foo"} on parent

Comment: @karen I do not want to ignore unknown, because I want to avoid setting some (existing) properties by the caller of a REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a custom `BeanDeserializerModifier`.

see here: [Jackson Dynamic filtering of properties during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305438/jackson-dynamic-filtering-of-properties-during-deserialization)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've redefined the annotation in Child class it overrides the one defined in Parent.

I know 2 Ways you could solve this, both of which are not straight forward.

1. In the Child class, instead of using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` make use of `@JsonIgnore` on the Getters of the Properties you would like to Ignore. This will make sure you're not overriding the Parent Annotation.
2. If you still want to make use of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, then Add a Custom [JsonFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria) and handle the annotations parsing manually in Runtime (*Reflections*) by looking if any of the hierarchical parent classes has a JsonIgnoreProperties then skip the assignment.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the second point: Is it sufficient to use a custom `JsonFilter` or do I need a customer deserializer?

Comment: @t777 Just a Custom JsonFilter should be enough.